# Where is bundled maven folder in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I am using bundled maven version with IntelliJ, and I would like to locate exactly where it is installed on disk, but I can't find the path. Someone knows where it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press **Execute Maven Goal** button,

[image]

and run `mvn -v` command

[image]

then you will get the bundled maven path and version :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can run any maven command and observe the Run window - the launched command and its output are displayed there.

In my case, on MacOS I can see:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java OTHER_PARAMS1 -Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3 OTHER_PARAMS2`